# What are the different named areas in c#?

Tags: c#

I have never bothered to see what the different areas in c# called, I did programming and never bothered to ask what is these area called. I'll post a picture to show what I mean. I've also looked online using google "c# script setup" with no prevail. Maybe someone here can help.

I like to find the names for, what is the area in the beginning called, the area where you initialize your settings, what are all the voids called, what do you call the class area.

[image]

Comment: C# code is text, and can be organized in any number of ways. What are the different parts of your question called?

Comment: Having said that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w2a9a9s3.aspx should get you started

Comment: @CodeIgnoto (1) are using directives.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by the question. If you're asking about the "areas of the code file" (1) and (3) they don't have names. The things you *put* there have names, but (3) in particular can go anywhere in your class.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - Some of those areas do have well-defined names.

Comment: @HenkHolterman not really. Some of those *language elements* have well-defined names, but you can put them in various places in the code file if you want. e.g. you can put `using` directives inside or outside a namespace, you can nest classes within each other, etc.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - one example where you're wrong: `using`s can only be _inside_ a namespace and then only as the first elements. Really. So that is named and positional.

Answer (score 2):

First, what you are declaring here is a class, not a script (that's just what unity uses it for).

- Area 1 are your using directives.
- Everything in the area 2 is called a **class definition**.
- Area 3 is not an area, as in theory you could declare your fields anywhere you like.
  But the part of the class definition you are referring to as Area 3 contains in this case some definitions of your class's **member fields** (these are not settings).
- Area 4 and Area 5 are **method definitions**. `void Start()` and `void
  Update()` are the **signatures** of the methods (a signature defines for example which arguments the method expects and what it returns, void meaning it returns nothing), and what comes in the block after it is the **method body**.

I'd suggest you learn a bit about C# basics though, as it will help you a lot when it comes to understanding the language. And it will make you a **much** better Unity developer. You need to understand that C# as used by Unity is not just simple scripting, it's a full programming language and provides much more possibilities than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code isn't too great because it is missing a `namespace`, an important element.

The top-level syntax (informal and incomplete) is

- 1 File-scope or compilation unit

  - 2 Namespace

    - 3 Type definitions

      - 4 Type members

1. The filescope is almost a namespace but this is the only place where `#define` and `#undefine` are allowed, and they must be first. The remainder can be considered as belonging to the namespace `global::`
2. Namespaces are the scope for other namespaces and Type definitions. The `using OtherNamespace;` directives are only allowed at the start of a namespace.
3. Type definitions include `class`, `struct` and `enum` definitions.
4. Type members include property, field  and method definitions. `void Start() {}` is a method.

Comment: Unity3D creates MonoBehaviours without namespaces, and it has various problems with namespaces as far as i know. Don't know if those have been fixed in more recent versions though.

Comment: This answer is about general C# , not about Unity.

Comment: I just wanted to explain why it doesn't have a namespace in this case :)

Comment: Yeah, got that. I just want to be clear about not knowing anything about Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, because some of the things your asking about have specific names, and other don't.

For starters, in general, C# doesn't care "where" in your code file you put things. It cares about what "containing scope" those things go into, which is determined by the sets of braces (`{ }`). In particular, the area you have labelled (3) has no name because the things you put there can go anywhere within (2), including being mixed in among the other things.

Strictly speaking, the only "areas" C# has that are location-dependent are regions: named areas in your code file that you designate with `#region / #endregion` directives. The things you have labelled are *language elements* of a C# program. You can find a very good overview of the types of language elements a program can have on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w2a9a9s3.aspx) or just about every beginner C# book ever written.

To answer your specific questions, here's sample code from that article that includes the typical elements you'd have:

```
// These are "import" statements used to refer to other namespaces.
using System;

// This is a namespace declaration, used to group related classes together.
// As far as I know, in Unity you don't use these.
namespace YourNamespace
{
    // Class definition: defining a new custom object type.
    public class Person
    {
        // Field: defining a new internal data element
        public string name;

        // Constructor that takes no arguments. 
        public Person()
        {
            name = "unknown";
        }

        // Method: defining a new behavior for your class.
        public void SetName(string newName)
        {
            name = newName;
        }
    }
}
```